# Deactivate PayPalPlus if the amount is higher than x

Tags: payment-methods

I want to deactivate or hide PayPalPlus from a certain shopping cart amount.

What is the best way to do this?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're using the Iways module.

Take a look into `Iways\PayPalPlus\Model\ConfigProvider` on line 184ff:

`return $this->method->isAvailable() ? [ [...]`

Best way imho would be to try setting an after-plugin on either the `getConfig()`-method, or `Iways\PayPalPlus\Model\Payment::isAvailable()`. You can then return `false` if your conditions are not met.